# point of making a stub file- knex

Tags: node.js, knex.js

for some test project, I avoided explicitly creating a [stub](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations), but, looking at the doc, they mentioned something like creating a stub file:

```
knex migrate:make --stub
```

which according to configurations we specify created `<filename>.stub`. I looked at someone's starter pack, and saw that it was a file similar to migrations file.

So, from what I knew from  my novice experience, altering, creating table is possible from migrations, and filling test data is possible from seeds. So, why do we need a `.stub` file for both the migrations and seeds?(which by the way seem similar) What's the whole concept of the `.stub`  file?

Answer (score 0):

The stub file is just a template to be copy-pasted as your new migration.

E.g. you call `knex migrate:make new_migration`

knex will create a file `$timestamp_new_migration.$extension` and the contents of the file will be the content of your `stub` file.